# curl pthreads issue (out of resources) on php 7x86

Tags: php, curl, pthreads

Here's the the simple demonstrative snippet:

```
 <?php 
class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
    private $workerId;
    private $url;

    public function __construct($string)
    {
        $this->url = $string;
    }

    public function run()
    {

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);

        if ($this->post) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->post);
        }

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        //echo $response;
        curl_close($curl);
    }
}

$data = file('urls.txt'); 
$data_size = count($data);
// Worker pool
$workers = [];
$t_count = 100;
$flag = 1;
$k = 0;

while($flag === 1)
{   

    $c_w = count($workers);

    if($c_w < $t_count)
    {
        for($i = $c_w; $i<$t_count - $c_w;$i++)
        {
            if($k >= $data_size)
            {
                $flag = 0;
                break;
            }   

            $url = explode("|",$data[$k]);
            $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($url[0]);
            echo $k." ".$url[0]."\n";
            $workers[$i]->start();
            $k++;   
        }

    }

    $c_w = count($workers);
    for($i=0;$i<$c_w;$i++)
    {
        if($workers[$i]->join())
        {
            //echo "joining $i\n";
            unset($workers[$i]);

        }
    }


}

?>
```

The problem that I can't understand is that on php 7x86 I always getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: cannot start WorkerThreads, out of reso
rces in C:\Users\alex\Desktop\test.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\alex\Desktop\test.php(56): Thread->start()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\alex\Desktop\test.php on line 56
```

For some reason this not appear in php 7 x64 version (with same ini settings). Why is that happening? Thanks!

upd: Also there is no info about this case on google. Asked it in few communities, but no one seems to know about how to fix this or even why exception raises.

Comment: 32-bit processes have much more limited address space than 64-bit processes do. You should probably just limit the number of threads you create to some reasonable number, say 100.

Comment: It doesn't even works with 50 threads. 100 is desirable value for me at the moment.

Comment: What resource limit have you set in `php.ini`? You probably need at least 1MB per thread.

Comment: I've got 3000mb set in php.ini:
memory_limit=3000M

Comment: You need to chunck your pool batches  according to the nb of available cpu threads. This is especialy tru with pthreads v3. After each join batch complited, unset the pool.

Comment: @cpugourou, but why this works okay on x64?

Comment: Ressouces allocation is different. Also pthreads uses massive ram ressources , especialy when you are dealing with big arrays inside them. Avoid as much a possible to pass arrays to the workers and use variables mostly. Execute queries, curl etc inside them. If your workers generates arrays, chunck you pool and never go over your cpu threads, unset and force garbage collection after each batch . This is good for 32 or 64. More you apply those rules, faster your pthreads workers will be. 10 batches of 12 threads (6 cores) are much faster than throuing 120 in one pool.

Comment: @cpugourou, I'am using threads actually, and it consumes much less resources that pc has. The x64 php 7 version runs near 150 curl threads fine, but x86 can't run even 50. That's a sad limitation.

Comment: it s nothing to do with 32 or 64. first you d better use multicurl instead of pthreads and as you are using php7 go to this thread where we have discussed it already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857779/why-not-all-threads-are-completed/34888049#34888049

Comment: @cpugourou, I've already created several threads at SO and created an issue. For my needs I must use pthreads for paralleling several tasks. However, I still got no answer from the developer about that behaviour of pthreads on php 7 x86 version.